# Sanitizing input fields in express app

Tags: mongodb, express, post

I have several input fields for emails on my website. For these, I have 1 POST-route:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    Email.create(req.body.email, function(err, newEmail){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.redirect('/');
        };
    });
});
```

The bootcamp I am learning from tells me that nefarious actors could use scripts in these inputs. However, when I try something like this:

```
<script>alert('test')</script>
```

nothing happens. In fact, it just gets added to my mongo database.

I installed express-sanitizer anyway as the bootcamp suggested and did this:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    req.body.email = req.sanitize(req.body.email);
    Email.create(req.body.email, function(err, newEmail){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.redirect('/');
        };
    });
});
```

However, when I do this and I input something I get an error stating 'ObjectParameterError' when I put in any string or script.

My app.use's look like this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(expressSanitizer());
```

Any suggestions on how to best protect myself against scripts and how to implement express-sanitizer correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with how you're doing the value changing.

I've done mine like this and it works:

```
const expressSanitizer = require('express-sanitizer')
let bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}))
//For Sanitising SQL
app.use(expressSanitizer())
```

And then when I want to sanitise:

```
//Pulling the sanitised values from request body
var name = req.sanitize(req.body.name)
var email = req.sanitize(req.body.email)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sanitizing entire object try to sanitize only the required one.

`req.body.email = req.sanitize(req.body.email)` should look like this `req.body.email.yoursanitizationfield = req.sanitize(req.body.email.yoursanitizationfield);`

````
    req.body.email.yoursanitizationfield = req.sanitize(req.body.email.yoursanitizationfield);
    Email.create(req.body.email, function(err, newEmail){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.redirect('/');
        };
    });
});```
````

Answer (score -2):

Can I suggest adding some debugging to get insights to program execution. Add a `console.log(req.body.email);` after `req.body.email = req.sanitize(req.body.email);` to see if that has worked? (Or indeed if the execution has even reached that point.)